# How can i change icon of my android app

Tags: android

i want want to change icon of my android app.

my icon name is "ic_launcher" and i have replaced the default ic_launcher icon in "drawable-hdpi" with my new icon having the same name "ic_launcher" now my emulator shows the new icon but my mobile phone(samsung Glaxy-GT-S5830) does not shows this new icon

Answer (score 1):

you can replace icon file drawable-ldpi folder in your Project...!

because samsung galaxy gt-s5830 resolution is 320x240!

Answer (score 1):

Just try restarting your phone once and check.

And also please check whether you have new .apk file installed on your phone in which you have changed your icon.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace all the icons of same name.
Or you can place the icon with different name, and assign this new file(with proper name) as icon in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I just did a clean and build and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your phone has a different screen resolution than what's defined in the emulator. Android will select an icon that is the appropriate size for the device it's installed on, and it decides this based on the names of the directories it finds in the package. If you replaced the icon in drawable-hdpi, you should also replace it in the rest of the drawable-?dpi directories with equivalent icons of the appropriate sizes, so different pixel densities are accommodated.